# How to specify values based on data frame conditions in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr

I have a data frame `df` that has an ID-column (called SNP) in which some IDs occur more than once.

```
     CHR   SNP    A1 A2    MAF NCHROBS
1:    1    1:197  C  T 0.3148     314
2:    1    1:205  G  C 0.2058     314
3:    1    1:206  A  C 0.0000     314
4:    1    1:219  C  G 0.8472     314
5:    1    1:223  A  C 0.7265     314
6:    1    1:224  G  T 0.3295     314
7:    1    1:197  C  T 0.3148     314
8:    1    1:205  G  C 0.0000     314
9:    1    1:206  A  C 0.0000     314
10:   1    1:219  C  G 0.0000     314
11:   1    1:223  A  C 0.0000     314
12:   1    1:224  G  T 0.0000     314
13:   1    1:197  C  T 0.4753     314
14:   1    1:205  G  C 0.1964     314
15:   1    1:206  A  C 0.0000     314
16:   1    1:219  C  G 0.6594     314
17:   1    1:223  A  C 0.8946     314
18:   1    1:224  G  T 0.2437     314
```

I would like to calculate the mean and standard deviation (SD) from the values in the MAF-column that share the same ID.

```
df <-
    list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>%
    map_df(~fread(.))

colMeans(df, rows=df$SNP == "1:197", cols=df$MAF)
```

Why is it not possible to specify values based on conditions with colMeans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a `data.table`,

```r
df[, .(mu = mean(MAF), sigma = sd(MAF)), by = .(SNP) ]
#      SNP        mu      sigma
# 1: 1:197 0.3683000 0.09266472
# 2: 1:205 0.1340667 0.11620023
# 3: 1:206 0.0000000 0.00000000
# 4: 1:219 0.5022000 0.44493914
# 5: 1:223 0.5403667 0.47545926
# 6: 1:224 0.1910667 0.17093936
```

If you prefer base (despite using `data.table`), then

```r
aggregate(dat$MAF, list(dat$SNP), function(a) c(mu = mean(a), sigma = sd(a)))
#   Group.1       x.mu    x.sigma
# 1   1:197 0.36830000 0.09266472
# 2   1:205 0.13406667 0.11620023
# 3   1:206 0.00000000 0.00000000
# 4   1:219 0.50220000 0.44493914
# 5   1:223 0.54036667 0.47545926
# 6   1:224 0.19106667 0.17093936
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is great that the 'data.table' solution is a one-liner.

Comment: Technically, the way `data.table` can chain operations with repeating `[` blocks, one can do a lot on one line with `dat[...][...][...][...]` ... though the line *width* might be daunting :-) (Yes, `data.table` does this *well*.)

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(SNP) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(MAF),
            sd = sd(MAF))
```

Gives us:

```
 SNP    mean     sd
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1:197 0.368 0.0927
2 1:205 0.134 0.116 
3 1:206 0     0     
4 1:219 0.502 0.445 
5 1:223 0.540 0.475 
6 1:224 0.191 0.171
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as to why colMeans is not working:

1. If you look at the doucmentation of colMeans using `?colMeans` you will realize that you are passing the wrong named arguments. The docs give the following example: `colMeans(x, na.rm=FALSE, dims=1)`. And you will realize, that it doesn't have (or takes) any arguments named `rows` and `cols`. So when you try to run your code, you will get the `unused arguments error`.
2. As to the question, if it is possible to pass conditional statements in `colMeans` you will have to pass those statements with `df`, i.e. you can pass the subset of `df` as follows:

```r
colMeans(df[df$SNP == "1:197", "MAF", drop=F], na.rm=F, dims=1)
```

3. Note it is important to pass the argument `drop=F` in this case, as you are subsetting on single column. When you subset on single column, `[` operator simplies the result and convert the `dataframe` to `numeric vector`. But when using `drop=F`, it preserves the dimension of originally passed `dataframe`.
4. If a numeric vector is passed to `colMeans` you will get an error as the `colMeans` accept `x` to be of atleast `2` dimensions.
5. As to the other question of how to calculate column mean, I believe others have highlighted quite nice approaches in this thread, any of those approaches work, you just have to choose one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tapply()` function, given SNP is a `factor`:

```
  mean.CHR=tapply(df$SNP,df$MAF,mean)

  sd.CHR=tapply(df$SNP,df$MAF,sd)
```